# How do I set the font at cursor?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I have a NSTextView and I want to set the font at the cursor (cursor: insertion point cursor, the flashing bar) , meaning at the cursor, the font becomes Times New Roman (example). Wherever the cursor is at, I want the font to change. I tried doing

```
[self.textView.textStorage addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [NSFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:14]} range:NSMakeRange([[[self.textView selectedRanges] objectAtIndex:0] rangeValue].location, 0)];
```

But it was not working. Is there another way? I tried a number of things, and I still have problems.

Comment: What do you mean by set font at the cursor?

Comment: I explained it a bit better now.

Comment: This is sooooooo confusing.  Why would you want to change the font of text that is underneath a cursor?

Comment: @heading_to_tahiti You know, like in Microsoft Word when you change font, you start typing in it. I want that.

Comment: you want to be able to add several font styles in the textView? or change all the text to one font at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it would be helpful to avoid confusion between "cursor" as in the mouse cursor (e.g. pointing arrow or I-beam) and, what I assume you mean, "cursor" as in insertion point or selection.

The attributes that will be used for newly-typed text are stored in the text view's `typingAttributes` property. So, you would do:

```
NSMutableDictionary* attributes = [textView.typingAttributes mutableCopy];
attributes[NSFontAttributeName] = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:14];
self.textView.typingAttributes = attributes;
```

Of course, if there's a selection, you would usually want to change the font in all of the selected ranges in addition to setting the typing attributes. You would use `rangesForUserCharacterAttributeChange` for that.

Comment: Ill try that. I might also try to condense it. It seems ti work better sometimes.